# Sliding door button with variable height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to use [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lswk4.png) as a background for a button:

[image: Background Image]

The button should have dynamic width, which is not a problem if I use the [sliding door](http://css-tricks.com/examples/Sprites+SlidingDoors-Button/) technique. But if you look closely the image: the top and the bottom edge is a bit curvy, so it won't work.

I tried to stretch the image, but the edges became blurry.

Does somebody know a solution for this problem?
Any idea is appreciated!

*Edit:*
Some of the pages already have few buttons with fix width/height and each of them a "personal" background: so they look sharp. If I use the image-stretch technique on "my" button, then there will be contrast between them, because this one won't look that sharp.

Comment: @Dušan Radojević  I forgot to say that the button will contain text with variable length

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you could do it with CSS,
and you can keep the image if you wouldto do that:

```
button{
  height:50px;
  background-image:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/lswk4.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: `background-size` is only supported by IE9+

Comment: Yes, it works in FF, Chrome and Safari, but my point was that older versions of IE do not support it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
div{
  height:50px;
}
div img {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

<div><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lswk4.png" /></div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Q8f9t/4/